# Run a specific test in Protractor

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

How can run a specific test scenario in my angular app. what I mean by this is that I implemented a new feature in protractor, created the page and the step, but I already have other features implemented. What I'm asking is if there's a way to test only the feature I added.

Comment: I don't know where to implement it? I'm a newbie. Can you please give me more simplified steps. Btw i guess i should mention that i work with 'Give' and 'Then' in the steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, there are 2 ways

1. instead of `describe` or `it` use `fdescribe` and `fit` respectively. `f` stands for focus. This will run only focused blocked
2. In your config, there is `spec` property which can take an array of specs or a single path. Just specify the path to your spec you want to run

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to skip tests as follows:

instead of `describe` use `xdescribe` to skip a whole test suite.

instead of `it` use `xit` to skip a single test.

Skip all the suites except your new one!

This is not a great solution since you have to manually add the `x` and then delete it when you don't want to skip anymore. Depends how many other test suites you have, whether this is suitable.

It may be possible to make the skipping conditional based on some variable or config value. Here's how to make skipping conditional with mocha - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42586302/1205871

This may work with protractor tests too, worth a try!