# Excluding a whole folder in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have the following folder architecture:

[image]

I'm using Typescript and would like to run all *.cy.ts files except the ones in "Other tests" folder.

All tests within "Other tests" are skipped, but I would like to prevent 'cypress run' to display them, even if skipped.

I've tried using the exclude object in 'tsconfig.json' as:

```
    "exclude": [
        "*/Other tests/**.cy.ts",
        "*/Other tests/*.ts",
      ]
```

But it's not working. My tests in are still displayed on the terminal as skipped.
Can anyone help me here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe this will help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723167/how-to-programmatically-skip-a-test-in-mocha

Comment: What version of Cypress are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cypress version 10.7

Comment: Thanks for the link above but that's not working either.
I've tried it.skip and describe.skip.
I have 19 tests in total and I still see (1 of 19) when running 'cypress run'.